# Changing individual column width in treeview in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Here i have a code and i want to have different column width to different columns,is there a way to do this? Here the width is 120 but i dont want all columns to have 120 width jus a specific column and i want others columns to have different wdith? Any suggestion? Thanks in advance :)

Code :

```
def all_logs():
    log = Toplevel(root)
    log.transient(root)
    log.title('View all Visitors')

    # setup treeview
    columns = ('ID', 'S_ID', 'S_NAME', 'B_NAME', 'Date_Taken', 'Due_Date','Date_Returned', 'Status')
    tree = ttk.Treeview(log, height=20, columns=columns, show='headings')
    tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

    # setup columns attributes
    for col in columns:
        tree.heading(col, text=col)
        tree.column(col, width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # fetch data
    con = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='*****', database='DB')
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM library')
    

    # populate data to treeview
    for rec in c:
        tree.insert('', 'end', value=rec)

    # scrollbar
    sb = tk.Scrollbar(log, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
    sb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    tree.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    a = tree.item(tree.focus())['values']

    btn = tk.Button(log, text='Close', command=log.destroy, width=20, bd=2, fg='red')
    btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    con.close()
```

Comment: You can use `columns = (('ID', 100), ...)` instead.  Then update the for loop to cater the change.

Comment: u mean tht i vl have to edit this part out? ```for col in columns:
        tree.heading(col, text=col)
        tree.column(col, width=120, anchor=tk.CENTER)``` ? or something else? could you be give a code to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the required widths alongside with the column names:

```
columns = (
    ('ID', 50),
    ('S_ID', 50),
    ('S_NAME', 120),
    ('B_NAME', 120),
    ('Date_Taken', 100),
    ('Due_Date', 100),
    ('Date_Returned', 100),
    ('Status', 50),
)
```

Then you need to extract the column names when creating the treeview:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(log, height=20, columns=[x[0] for x in columns], show='headings')
```

And configure the column headings and widths:

```
for col, width in columns:
    tree.heading(col, text=col)
    tree.column(col, width=width, anchor=tk.CENTER)
```