# what tkinter widget should use to display and store data? Its okay to use a label? I'm using sqlite3 for database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, widget

```py
def query():
    global record
    conn = sqlite3.connect('billing.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM billing")
    records = c.fetchall()
    # print(records)

    print_records = ''
    for record in records:
        print_records += str(record[0]) + "    " + str(record[1]) + "         " + str(record[2]) \
                         + "     " + str(record[3]) + "     " + str(record[4]) + "     " + str(record[5]) \
                         + "     " + str(record[6]) + "     " + str(record[7]) + "\n"

        show = Label(root, width=120,  text=print_records, anchor=NW)
        show.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        show.place(x=402, y=50, height=510)
        show.config(font=("TimesNewRoman", 10))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Store data? As in storing data in a new file? Or just showing data? Anyway `ttk.Treeview` is worth a look, rather just using label.

Comment: I'm new in python and in this kind of community, I just want to create a system that can store a lot of records and to display it also in the interface. because i dont know how to connect treeview widget to Entry widget and database. can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of using `ttk.Treeview` to display your data from database:

```
def query():
    # Same code above...
    records = [('Hello','World'),('This','is'),('Treeview','widget')] # This will c.fetchall()
    
    cols = ('First column','Second columns') # Change this with whatever you want your column name to be
    tree = ttk.Treeview(root,columns=cols,show='headings',height=100)
    tree.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

    for col in cols: # Set treeview attributes
        tree.heading(col,text=col)
        tree.column(col,width=100,anchor='center')

    for items in records: # Insert values inside the treeview
        tree.insert('','end',values=items)
```

Keep in mind that since this is a `ttk` widget, you will have to import it first:

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

If you want your column to have separate widths, then check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61905007/13382000)

Comment: Thankyou for this code. but my another problem is once i clicked query to show the record it duplicates all the records stored in database ? I want only to show and check the record if its added into the database, if what is the latest record added into it .

Comment: @SpencerHolland Maybe it is the way you have implemented it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971555/13382000).

Comment: Thankyou @Cool Cloud :)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpqBw.png)

Once I clicked the query to show in treeview widget, it duplicates all the records in database. How to remove duplicate records and show only the records that has been added in database?

```
def show(self):
    global record
    conn = sqlite3.connect('billing.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM billing")
    self.records = c.fetchall()

    for items in self.records:
        self.table.insert('', 'end', values=items)
```